# Is a driving license issued by a European country valid as ID in Italy?

Tags: european-union, identification, italy

I'm an Italian citizen resident in Hungary, both are part of EU.

I'm trying to understand if a driving license issued by Hungary would be accepted as a valid ID in Italy. I searched online and I found this information (emphasis mine):

> Secondo la legge italiana, per documento di identità si intende ogni documento emesso da una Pubblica Amministrazione italiana (**o di un altro Paese**) che abbia la finalità di identificare la persona che ne è il titolare.
>
> Source | https://www.money.it/Documenti-di-identita-quali-sono-quando-scadono

Translates approximately to:

> According to the italian law, an identity document means any document issued by an Italian public administration (**or from another country**) that has the purpose of identifying the person who is the owner.

If the above is correct, I seem to understand that a Hungarian driving license would be considered valid.

I'm looking for some authoritative source to confirm the above statement.

Answer (score 1):

The **prevailing purpose** of a driver's licence is to document which types of motor vehicles you are allowed to drive.

It is not an identification document (no citizenship entry for one thing).

It can sometimes be accepted as such, depending on the situation, but do not assume that will always be the case.

For the crossing of internal Schengen borders, a driver's licence is not accepted.

---

> [DPR 445/2000](http://www.parlamento.it/parlam/leggi/deleghe/00443dla.htm)
> (Legislative provisions on administrative documentation)
> Article 1 (R)
> Definitions
>
> 1. For the purposes of this consolidated act, the following definitions apply:
>    ...
>    d) IDENTITY DOCUMENT the identity card and any other document with a photograph issued, on paper, magnetic or computer support, by the competent administration of the Italian State or of other States, **with the *prevailing purpose* of proving the personal identity** of its owner;
>    ...

---

**Sources**:

- [Carta d'identità](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/documenti_di_viaggio)

  - [DPR 445/2000](http://www.parlamento.it/parlam/leggi/deleghe/00443dla.htm)
  - [Identification document in Italy - Wikipedia](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Documento_di_riconoscimento_in_Italia)

Comment: In Italy a driver's license **is** an identification document

Comment: @FezVrasta no, it is not. It is a document you can use to identify yourself in *some* occasions, but it is not an ID.

Comment: It is, read the law. It’s the only reason why I’m asking if a not Italian driving license is valid too.

Comment: @FezVrasta Because a driver's licence issued in Italy can also be issued to non Italians, thus is not a complete replacement of a Carta d'identità (which is issued only to Italians).

Answer (score 0):

## No.

Italy has an official ID. ID is Identity Document. The *Carta d’identità*. While generally a driver's license contains most information of an ID and does qualify to prove who you are (*can serve to identify*), it *is not an ID*, neither in Italy (as [Italian Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carta_d%27identit%C3%A0#In_Italia) tells me), nor in the EU. It does lack *some* information required to make it a proper ID.

A valid EU-ID follows [Directive 2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32004L0038). It needs to contains your residence address and statehood as well as some other extra information, which simply are not on a driver's license. This is an Italian ID:

[image]

Comment: The UK is in the EU - for now - and accepts a driving licence (issued by any country) as a valid ID document.
 https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/40/section/7?timeline=false

Comment: @RickApe But it is not accepted as a border crossing document. A driving licence is (and will remain), for the purposes of sections 4 to 6 (Possession, Counterfeiting and Possession of false identity documents) of the **[Identity Documents Act 2010](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/40/section/7?timeline=false)**.

Comment: @Mark Johnson. True, but this thread concerns the validity of certain documents to establish one's identity. Neither the OP nor Trish (to whom I added my comment) mentioned border crossing.

Comment: @RickApe there's a difference between "Can establish who you are" and "Is an ID" (=Identity Document).

Comment: @RickApe Since the prevailing purpose of a driver's licence is to document which types of motor vehicles you are allowed to drive, it does not fullfill the condition of an *identity document* under Article 1 (1)(d) of the Italian law DPR 445/2000, which requires that the prevailing purpose is to prove the personal identity of its owner.

Comment: Driving license is a complete replacement to “carta d’identità” in Italy - within italian borders